# A transaction is stuck?

Tags: out-of-gas, error

This transaction will reach the recipient? Or not?

[image]https://etherscan.io/tx/0x99fb756ea14c57989827e7c9a49c6aa68d5ff2a7b8fd3faecd3021c2dece3115

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has failed and any changes to the blockchain are reverted. Hence the receiver will not receive your ERC20 tokens.

Your gas limit is too low. Increase your gas limit.